# How to retrieve max

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have this function with php using oop and mysql, can somebody tell me what's the error in my code, i'm completely new to oop,

```
private function add_img($whichimg) {

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT max(gallery_id) as maxi FROM gallery") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $this->maximum = $row["maxi"];

    $add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO gallery (title,gallery_id) VALUES('$whichimg','$this->maximum')") or die(mysql_error());
    return $add_to_db;
}
```

Comment: What IS the error in your code, exactly? We don't know what sort of error you ran into.

Comment: not an oop, gallery_id should be an autoincrement field and omitted from the query. your code will get the max value (say 1) and the insert the new record with the same value (1 again). You should +1 it if you keep to this method.

Comment: looks like you are missing a Group By clause in your select query

Comment: You dont need a group by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html

Comment: What is your code supposed to do and what isn't working? What's your expected result and what's your actual result? Are there error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The error is here: `'$this->maximum'`

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO gallery (title,gallery_id) VALUES('$whichimg','".$this->maximum."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO gallery (title,gallery_id) VALUES('$whichimg','{$this->maximum}')") or die(mysql_error());
```

or even better

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO gallery (title,gallery_id) VALUES('%s','%s')", $whichimg, $this->maximum);
    $this->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: just spotted that too LOL ;-)

Comment: the 3th way is my favorite because you can easy output $sql for debugging

Comment: +1 yeah the 3rd option is better for readability, especially when there are a lot of variables.

Comment: Actually i copied and pasted all three and still doesn't work, as in nothing gets inserted in the database.


I did try this, which in an improvement since the title is inserted but the gallery_id gets inserted an empty value '0':


$maxid1=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(gallery_id) FROM gallery");
  $maxid=mysql_fetch_array($maxid1);
  
     $add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO gallery (title,gallery_id) VALUES('$whichimg','$maxid')") or die(mysql_error());
     return $add_to_db;

Comment: I found the error, which wasn't in the insert query but in the select query it had to be $maxid1=$this->query("SELECT MAX(gallery_id) as maxi FROM gallery");
instead of $maxid1=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(gallery_id) FROM gallery");